# Retrieving a number out of a text paragraph using selenium

Tags: selenium, xpath, selenium-webdriver

My application sends a text message on a registered mobile no. as

"Dear Customer, Your One Time Passcode is 36842159. Please use this Passcode to complete your transaction. Thank you."

I am accessing the sms over a webapp.I am trying to retrieve the passcode generated and enter it on my page to check for validation but since its a text message, the complete body of message has same div and xpath.

Please suggest a way to store the dynamically generated passcode from the message.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your SMS text is same for each message, you can extract the number from String and use it for your validation.

```
String sms = "Dear Customer, Your One Time Passcode is 36842159. Please use this Passcode to complete your transaction. Thank you.";
String passcode = sms.substring(0, sms.indexOf(". Please use this Passcode to complete your transaction. Thank you."));
passcode = passcode.replace("Dear Customer, Your One Time Passcode is ", "");
System.out.println(passcode);//Use it in you login.
```

You may use any other way to extract the passcode. It should just be manipulating your original string.

Comment: Although I didnt specify the later string i.e. ". Please use this Passcode to comp...", it still worked. Thanks man